# How to using one route with multiple dto on Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, validation, dto, nestjs, class-validator

Currently I am using NestJS to build restful api.
I am having a `ValidationPipe` problem. it only works at controller method and  not working with service methods.

I need to make choices for different `DTO` class (`UserCreateDTO`, `StaffCreateDTO`,...) for each `ROLE` (admin, staff, user) on a `route`.

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Comment: Still having problems?

Answer (score 3):

Pipes only work on controllers, you cannot use them with services. But you can just use class-validator's `validate` method (together with class-transformer's `plainToClass` method) anywhere in your code instead:

```
const user = plainToClass(UserCreateDto, userRequestEntity);
const errors = await validate(user)
if (errors.length > 0) {
  throw this.createError(errors);
}
```

---

Also, you don't need to create multiple DTO classes for different roles. Just use `class-validator` [groups](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-groups):

Assign each property in your DTO to one or multiple groups (= roles):

```
@Min(12, {groups: ['admin', 'staff']})
age: number;
@Length(2, 20, {groups: ['admin']})
name: string;
```

Then pass your group (roles) to `plainToClass` and `validate`.

```
// Pass your roles as groups
const groups = ['admin'];

// Transform to class with groups
const entityClass = plainToClass(EntityDto, entity, { groups })

// Validate with groups
const errors = await validate(entityClass, { groups });
```