# two dtos for one controller in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I'm trying to get different types of dtos from body. If firstDto is incoming get it and transform, if secondDto is incoming transform it to secondDto. But it's not working and I have no idea. Here is my code;

```
@Controller('log')
export class LogsController {
  constructor(private logsService: LogsService) {}

  @Post()
  async createStatusLog(@Body() body: CreateMessageDto | CreateStatusDto) {
    console.log(body.constructor.name);
    return body;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useValue: new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
        transform: true,
      }),
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to using one route with multiple dto on Nestjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081080/how-to-using-one-route-with-multiple-dto-on-nestjs)

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei thank you. That resolved my issue. I used plainToInstance with my DTOs to check if it matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
  @Post()
  async createStatusLog(@Body() dto1: CreateMessageDto, @Body() dto2: CreateMessageDto CreateStatusDto) {
    console.log(body.constructor.name);
    return body;
  }
```